# PDE problem related to the method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Here is the question : Suppose all solutions $u(x,t)$ to $au_x+bu_t=0$ satisfy $u(1,2)=u(3,6)$. What is $b/a$ ?

Along its characteristic curves $bx-at=c$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$, we know that $u$ is constant. These characteristics fill in the $xt-plane$ and if we suppose that $(1,2)$ and $(3,6)$ lie on the same characteristic, then the problem is easy. However, what if they don't ? This is, I think a possible case but can't figure out the solution. 
Thank you for any hint or advice !

Comment: The general solution of the PDE is $$u(x,t)=F(bx-at)$$ where $F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to some condition. The condition $u(1,2)=u(3,6)=F(b-2a)=F(3b-6a)=F(3(b-2a))$ implies $$F(X)=F(3X)$$ If you are able to solve this functional equation the problem is solved. If not, the problem has no solution satisfying the specified condition. In fact they are an infinity of solutions : $F(X)=C$ where $C$ is any constant. Thus the answer of your question is $$u(x,t)=C$$ whatever $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: why does this imply that $F(X)=F(3X)$ ?

Comment: See above : $F(b-2a)=F(3(b-2a))$. Let $X=b-2a$. Thus $F(X)=F(3X)$.

Comment: ok but not for arbitrary X, sorry this was my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @JJacquelin almost solves the problem. If all solutions satisfy $u(1,2) = u(3,6)$, then we deduce from $u(x,t) = F(bx - at)$ that
$$
F(b - 2a) = F\big(3(b - 2a)\big)
$$
must be satisfied **for all** $F$. This means that both arguments are equal, i.e. that $b/a = 2$.

Comment: do we have that the arguments are equal because the functions F are arbitrary ?

Comment: @Malik yes. Since the function $F$ is arbitrary, it can for instance be equal to the identity function. Hence, the arguments are equal